# Finding a keyword from one file in another file

Tags: c

So my project for class needs me to find a list of keywords from one file:

```
Master's,Bachelor's,Professor
```

And needs me to find it through a resume in another file:

```
John Smith 
1234 Residence Road 
johnsmith@gmail.com

Degree level: Bachelor's degree
Major: Applied mathematics

Work Experience:

Professor at local university for multiple math classes, mainly calculus
Worked at a tech company studying the analytics of their online store
```

Now I have the keywords stored in an array of `char spacing[10][15]` (with no commas)
and I have the resume saved as `char* buffer`. Both work, as they both print out, but when trying to find the keywords I keep getting 0 (`int KWcount` is the counter for the amount of times a keyword appears). Here's the code both putting the resume into buffer and my attempt at finding the words.

```
//Resume
FILE* fp2;
fp2 = fopen("resume.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("\nFile not found.\n");
    return 0;
}
//File Reading
fseek(fp2, 0L, SEEK_END);
numbytes = ftell(fp2);
fseek(fp2, 0L, SEEK_SET);
buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char));
if (buffer == NULL)
    return 1;
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, fp2);
fclose(fp2);

printf("Before process: %i", KWcount);

//Search for keyword
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (strcmp(buffer, spacing[i]) == 0) {
        KWcount++;
    }
}
printf("\n\nAfter process:%i\n", KWcount);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

```
Before process:0
After process:0
```

I genuinely cannot figure out what the problem is and my professor is not really any help, so does anyone have any tips or ways to fix this?

Comment: No need to read the entire resume file into a buffer. Simply declare buffer long enough to hold the longest word (`64` bytes is fine -- longest word requires `29` chars including the `'\0'`). Then simply open the resume file and loop `while (fscanf (fp, "%63s", buffer) == 1) { /* do your compare on buffer here */ }`. Much simpler. Other option is to read a line-at-a-time and tokenize the line -- but why? `fscanf()` with the `"%63s"` will read each whitespace separated word while protecting the array bound for `buffer`. (always use the *field-width* modifier with `"%s"`)

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp(buffer, spacing[i])`
strcmp will return 0 only if the two arguments point to strings which are exactly equal. What you need to do is search `buffer` word by word and then compare those with the word you expect to find.
You may find the function `strtok` useful to break apart your resume buffer into words.

And also I recommend using `strncmp`, since it allows you to cap the maximum number of characters in your comparison. After all, your goal is to compare just a single word from the resume, not the entire string.